# Is there a way to hide multiple rows on another tab in Google sheets when a checkbox is checked?

Tags: google-sheets

I have a Google Sheet I would like to hide multiple rows on another tab in the sheet when clicking a checkbox. I have multiple checkboxes that need to hide certain rows. I will be adding many more but for now this is what I have.

Example of what I am looking to do:

If C2 on Test tab is checked then hide rows 2-6 on Checklist tab
If C3 on Test tab is checked then hide rows 8-12 on Checklist tab
If C4 on Test tab is checked then hide rows 14-20 on Checklist tab
If C5 on Test tab is checked then hide rows 22-26 on Checklist tab
If C6 on Test tab is checked then hide rows 28-34 on Checklist tab
and so on and so forth

I will have alot more checkboxes to add and rows to hide eventually. Was hoping there is an easy way to do this. Any help would be appreciated.

Link to the sheet I am testing this on:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1tiP0WmM3VxImcnfON9w_oWnyDBVqG9LBY-r67anrA48/edit?usp=drivesdk

Comment: By "hide multiple rows on another tab" you mean move the cell to another tab or hide a cell in the Checklist tab based on another cell?

Comment: What I mean by hide the rows is the same as if you highlighted row 2-6, right clicked and selected hide rows 2-6, but in this case I would like to just check a box and have it hide those rows on a different tab automatically

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Make use of simple triggers

By following the constraints in your example the code needed is:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  // If the sheet name isn't Test or the column is not C just leave
  if (e.source.getActiveSheet().getName() !== 'Test' || e.range.getColumn() !== 3) return;

  var checkboxValue = e.range.getValue();
  var value = e.range.getA1Notation();
  if (checkboxValue) {
    switch(value) {
      case "C2":
        e.source.getSheetByName("Checklist").hideRows(2,5);
        break;
      case "C3":
        e.source.getSheetByName("Checklist").hideRows(8,5);
        break;
      case "C4":
        e.source.getSheetByName("Checklist").hideRows(14,7);
        break;
      case "C5":
        e.source.getSheetByName("Checklist").hideRows(22,5);
        break;
      case "C6":
        e.source.getSheetByName("Checklist").hideRows(28,7);
        break;
    }
  } else {
    switch(value) {
      case "C2":
        e.source.getSheetByName("Checklist").showRows(2,5);
        break;
      case "C3":
        e.source.getSheetByName("Checklist").showRows(8,5);
        break;
      case "C4":
        e.source.getSheetByName("Checklist").showRows(14,7);
        break;
      case "C5":
        e.source.getSheetByName("Checklist").showRows(22,5);
        break;
      case "C6":
        e.source.getSheetByName("Checklist").showRows(28,7);
        break;
    }
  }
}
```

Given your specific case if you wanted to add more items in your Checklist you will have to change the code.

### References

- [Event Objects](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#google_sheets_events)
- [onEdit()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers#onedite)

Comment: Your awesome Jose. Exactly what I wanted. I appreciate it. Thank you.